# Docker Debian .NET Core image bug

Tags: node.js, docker, .net-core, debian, single-page-application

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install wget gnupg \
    git \
    unzip
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
```

This is the docker file. I want to download nodejs to the container because I am building a spa app.

This is the error I get

```
=> ERROR [2/4] RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install wget gnupg     git     unzip                                                                                  1.0s
------
 > [2/4] RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install wget gnupg     git     unzip:
#5 0.932 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/b7ca340d6ca71e1f8e2ca05da724786dbd3dbab5cef724b237280668073608e1  File has unexpected size (13229 != 258108). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 199.232.110.132 80]
#5 0.932    Hashes of expected file:
#5 0.932     - Filesize:258108 [weak]
#5 0.932     - SHA256:b7ca340d6ca71e1f8e2ca05da724786dbd3dbab5cef724b237280668073608e1
#5 0.932     - MD5Sum:ec6c3fc6556b5b52078a8304148e403b [weak]
#5 0.932    Release file created at: Thu, 31 Dec 2020 15:31:33 +0000
#5 0.932 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/c88216232d353afbc95e57a5ad04fc515335fb75659dbcae6967cd1109b7e4fb  File has unexpected size (13179 != 7907472). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 199.232.110.132 80]
#5 0.932    Hashes of expected file:
#5 0.932     - Filesize:7907472 [weak]
#5 0.932     - SHA256:c88216232d353afbc95e57a5ad04fc515335fb75659dbcae6967cd1109b7e4fb
#5 0.932     - MD5Sum:6043a440cb8038062bed716e76b3d7e7 [weak]
#5 0.932    Release file created at: Sat, 05 Dec 2020 10:35:57 +0000
#5 0.932 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/55463230b47ea54463b1a8e687f24d60c0c8d4dccd1868ef26713e3fe11f7f20  File has unexpected size (13195 != 7860). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 199.232.110.132 80]
#5 0.932    Hashes of expected file:
#5 0.932     - Filesize:7860 [weak]
#5 0.932     - SHA256:55463230b47ea54463b1a8e687f24d60c0c8d4dccd1868ef26713e3fe11f7f20
#5 0.932    Release file created at: Fri, 01 Jan 2021 02:07:51 +0000
#5 0.932 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
------
```

I have tried looking into this error but have found nothing useful. If someone can suggest a different route to get nodejs on a container built from a dotnet core image that is fine as well. Thank you.

Comment: It also failed 6 hours ago. Maybe I try tomorrow?

Comment: So even when I try an ubuntu image, it still does not work and produces a very similar error. FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build-env

Answer (score 0):

When following these URL, they all throw `HTTP 404` (the mirror-sync error message is bogus). The error rather seems to stem from Microsoft's container registry. You'd have to use any other mirror from: https://www.debian.org/mirror/list ...or file an issue there: https://github.com/microsoft/containerregistry/issues

Comment: Sorry, but what should I specifically add to the docker file, assuming I want to use this mirror http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/

Comment: You're looking at the wrong file. Microsoft's registry is messed up; and they'd have to fix this.

Comment: This was not the problem. I get the same error when simply running apt-get using any ubuntu image.